# How to emulate Google Maps driving directions using pgRouting?

Tags: postgis, analysis, routing, network, pgrouting

Would like to emulate google maps' driving directions functionality but use pgRouting instead. google's data over the project area & scale is quite a bit off so we want to use our own transport network data in postGIS.

Any hints?

Comment: There are other routing services available on the web - are you interested in those or do you really want to spin your own?

Comment: I've never used pgrouting myself (should have, actually) but http://twitter.com/pgrouting seems to be a good source for latest information about the project and users.

Comment: roll our own. we're moving everything to postGIS & pgRouting works "well enough" for our first project area, just lacks directions.

Comment: "... pgRouting software options to support the creation of street route and turn-by-turn directions solutions..."  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrskbUiHhRw

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [OpenGraphRouter project](http://opengraphrouter.sourceforge.net/).

Stephen Woodbridge has created a [demo demonstrating the driving directions](http://gis.imaptools.com/routing/leaddog/?zoom=10&lat=33.85667&lon=35.52978&layers=B0TTTF&start=35.492313%2033.826188&stop=35.595811%2033.906827&method=STS&lang=eng).[Dead link]

There is a pretty good thread on the [PostGIS-users list related to this](http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-February/025967.html).[Dead link]

Comment: thanks, that email thread looks like a good place to start.

Comment: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-February/025907.html

Answer (score 1):

For setting up pgrouting and visualising it with Udig
[http://www.utdallas.edu/~ama054000/rt_tutorial.html][1] [Dead Link]

alternative link
http://www.davidgis.fr/blog/index.php?q=pgRouting

Make sure your using the right SRID,
common ones:
4326 - WGS 84 Long Lat, 4269 - NAD 83 Long Lat, 3395 - WGS 84 World Mercator, 2163 - US National Atlas Equal Area

Here is a good example of pgrouting in action with Open Street Map (Cloudmade 'Web Lite') Data

http://www.ridethecity.com/

route:
http://www.ridethecity.com/nyc?rid=866162
(icon markers are draggable and re-calculates route)

Comment: +1 for ridethecity.com, good example. The first link to utdallas is broken though.

Comment: The nearest to the now dead link is http://www.davidgis.fr/blog/index.php?q=pgRouting