# Does pgRouting support turn-by-turn routing?

Tags: pgrouting, network

I have route list as result of pgRouting with street names. How to get messages "Turn left", "Go along" etc ...
Can pgRouting do this or I need some other source and which?

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been discussed a few times already, see:

- [How to emulate Google Maps driving directions using pgRouting?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/823/driving-directions-in-pgrouting)
- http://postgis.refractions.net/pipermail/postgis-users/2010-February/025967.html
- http://www.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-users/2011-October/000849.html

If you are able to translate this from Italian, you may even use the function posted here: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-users/2011-January/000537.html

Comment: [Translated link to the funtion in 000537.html](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Flists.osgeo.org%2Fpipermail%2Fpgrouting-users%2F2011-January%2F000537.html&act=url) via Google Tranlate.

Comment: Dead links!!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Do you have Edge (topology) setup in your postgis database?

Example
pgRouting gives the ability to create the source-target (start-end nodes) information within PostgreSQL using assign_vertex_id():

```
SELECT assign_vertex_id(table_name, snapping_range, geometry_column_name, edge_id_column_name);
```

where table_name is the name of the edges table, nodes within snapping_range (value is in your current projection units) will be snapped, geometry_column_name is the name of the geometry column (usually ‘the_geom’), edge_id_column_name is the name of the edge id column (usually gid).

This function requires ‘source’ and ‘target’ integer fields.

```
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN source integer;
ALTER TABLE ways ADD COLUMN target integer;
SELECT assign_vertex_id('ways', 0.00001, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/howto/topology.html

Comment: I have all of this. I finished with routing, I have PgRouting Shorthest path output as gid and street name. But I want to have output like Google 1. Head west on 330th St toward Wagonwheel Rd    
  0.8 mi  
 2. Take the 2nd right onto US-56 E/​US-77 N
Continue to follow US-77 N   
  10.4 mi  
 3. Turn left onto KS-4 W    
  28.7 mi  
 4. Turn right onto KS-4 W/​S Gypsum Valley Rd    
  1.0 mi  
 5. Turn left onto KS-4 W    
  10.0 mi

Comment: I don't know how to write these messages "Head west on", "Take the 2nd right", "Continue to folow" etc.