# Computing driving directions in pgRouting/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, route, dijkstra

I have calculated shortest route/path by using pg_Dijkstra algorithm in PostGIS and it is working fine. Now how to calculate driving directions from starting edge to end edge. I have gone through the [link](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Driving-Direction-Instructions). But unable to go forward.

Is there any algorithm or procedure to calculate driving directions in PostGIS?

Comment: what is the difference between the shortest route and driving directions?

Comment: with driving directions the shortest route is "translated" into natural language and passed as directions to the driver (ie. turn left, go straight, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/823/how-to-emulate-google-maps-driving-directions-using-pgrouting